# where to add "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1"

Tags: android, ibus, android-studio

I don't know in which file I should add that line of code in order to fix input issues since my iBus is prior to 1.5.11

see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the linked page,

> Either upgrade IBus to version 1.5.11 **or** add "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" to your ~/.profile, then restart a session.

Add `export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1` to `~/.profile`, and restart your session. If that does not work, try upgrading IBus with `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

### Edit

Type `echo 'export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1' >> ~/.profile` into a bash shell.
That command `echo`s the text `export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1` into `~/.profile`.

Comment: I know but where can I find this "~/.profile" file and how to open it?

Comment: @Ziad `~` is your home directory. `~/.profile` is `/home/<username>/.profile`. Please view my edit.